# Import existing javascript site into VS 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I have an existing JS web page (using bower, gulp, and algular) that I want to work on in visual studio.

It is set up according to a different folder structure than the one that VS 2015 uses for ASP.NET projects, and I will only be working on the frontend (and there is no ASP.NET on the backend anyway).

Is there a way to import such a thing and develop in VS?

Ideally, I would like to keep all of the conveniences that VS offers for the ASP.NET projects (add bower dependencies via gui, folders for npm, debugger, ability to launch project as website and use the debugger, etc).

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: I typically have to resort to opening as a website but then it lacks the debugger etc... I'd be interested to know if there is an alternative as well.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes What are the other options?

Comment: If you open the project as a website, than at least your directory structure will remain intact and you can easily edit files from the solution explorer, you just can't debug etc... using visual studio.

Comment: Do you still get syntax highlighting/intellisense?

Comment: By hacking away at startup.cs I think I'm close. I was able to remove all of the other folders, most of the asp.net dependencies, and it still launches. Now I just need to set it so the right page opens at startup with content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a empty asp.net 5 project
2. copy the existing folders into the project folder
3. include the copied folders into the project

I believe the npm, bower json files must be in the root folder to be supported automatically by visual studio 2015.

Also front-end debugging is best done in your favorite browser.

Comment: My folder structure is totally different (more angular style). Can I just delete the other folders?

Comment: Your angular style folder structure would just fit in. What folders you want to delete specifically?

Comment: Also if you are only using visual studio as a editor with the functions you love, I.e not using iis express to host the development, I think you can feel free delete anything folders you like.

Comment: How can I get it to use index.html as the starting point (as opposed to just writing hello world)?

Comment: The fact that you are only dealing with front end,  I am guessing that your project is file based. If it is true, you could host your project using your exiting method before the importing. I will get back to you on how to get index.html shortly.

Comment: To serve index.html instead of hello world, open the startup.cs file at the root folder, find the method Configure, remove everything in the method, replace its content with these: app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles(); make sure your index.html is at the folder called wwwroot

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwv8C7WTV5o have a look of this tutorial, you need to add the nuget package called Microsoft.Aspnet.StaticFiles.